# How to grab the index numbers and wrap under the element 'locator'

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xslt-2.0

**Here we are try to extract the index numbers and moved into the new element 'locator'. See the below example:**

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<index>
<h1>Tax consequences of abandoning trade secret, 15.44&#x2013;15.45</h1>
<h2>Licensing agreement, address provision in, 8.34&#x0192;</h2>
<h3>Secretary of State&#x2019;s office, 9.13</h3>
<h2>Punitive and compensatory damages under federal constitutional maximum, 1.5-to-one ratio between, 12.22</h2>
<h4>Secretary of State&#x2019;s office, 19.13</h4>
<h5>Resolving ambiguities in insurance policy against insurer, 14.3</h5>
<h6>Bad faith lawsuit against competitor, antitrust consequences of, 11.2, 11.81</h6>
<h2>Consent to assignment, 8.43A&#x0192;, 9.10</h2>
<h2>Crime or fraud in misappropriation of trade secret, waiver of attorney-client privilege in cases of, 11.101</h2>
<h3>Representing clients in same field of technology, 17.10A</h3>
<h2>CCP &#x00a7;425.16, anti-SLAPP motions under, 11.29</h2>
<h3>CCP &#x00a7;2019.210, 11.44, 11.51, 11.53</h3>                    
</index>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<index>
<h1>Tax consequences of abandoning trade secret, <locator>15.44</locator>&#x2013;<locator>15.45</locator></h1>
<h2>Licensing agreement, address provision in, <locator>8.34&#x0192;</locator></h2>
<h3>Secretary of State&#x2019;s office, <locator>9.13</locator></h3>
<h2>Punitive and compensatory damages under federal constitutional maximum, 1.5-to-one ratio between, <locator>12.22</locator></h2>
<h4>Secretary of State&#x2019;s office, <locator>19.13</locator></h4>
<h5>Resolving ambiguities in insurance policy against insurer, <locator>14.3</locator></h5>
<h6>Bad faith lawsuit against competitor, antitrust consequences of, <locator>11.2</locator>, <locator>11.81</locator></h6>
<h2>Consent to assignment, <locator>8.43A&#x0192;</locator>, <locator>9.10</locator></h2>
<h2>Crime or fraud in misappropriation of trade secret, waiver of attorney-client privilege in cases of, <locator>11.101</locator></h2>
<h3>Representing clients in same field of technology, <locator>17.10A</locator></h3>
<h2>CCP &#x00a7;425.16, anti-SLAPP motions under, <locator>11.29</locator></h2>
<h3>CCP &#x00a7;2019.210, <locator>11.44</locator>, <locator>11.51</locator>, <locator>11.53</locator></h3>                    
</index>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<xsl:template match="//text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="((([0-9]+)([A-Z])?)\.([0-9A-Zƒ]+))">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="regex-group(1)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '(([0-9A-Z]+)\.([0-9A-Zƒ]+))', '&lt;locator&gt;$2.$3&lt;/locator&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

**Reference URL :** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwgDD/1

Comment: Well, if your code doesn't achieve the right result you need to explain what you want to achieve, i.e. define the format of "index numbers" and how they are different from e.g. `425.16` or `2019.210` you current code seems to wrap but your expected output doesn't show as wrapped.

Comment: @Martin Honnen - Yes its wrapping but those only the entries which we don't want like before the decimal have 4digit nums i.e. 2019.210 and the other which prefix entity '&#x00a7;' have i.e.  &#x00a7;425.16.

Comment: You need to define the "index number" format then exactly to allow you to write a more precise regular expression. We can't do that for you as we don't know the format from your single example.

Comment: @Martin Honnen - Yes Martin you are write, Can we modify the existing expression to handle the case which have 4digit before the decimal. And other one '1.5-to' we dont want wrap. please suggest

Comment: In a regular expression you can use quantifiers e.g. `[A-Z0-9]{1,3}` which might be of some help. But your text has e.g. `1.5` you don't seem to want to wrap and `9.10` you seem to want to wrap so it seems purely matching on the number of characters doesn't handle your text varieties.

Comment: @Martin Honnen - Thank you so much for your suggestion! I tried [A-Z0-9]{{1,3}} and \d{{3}} etc. but unable get the output. we handling under the attribute thats why using double curly braces.

Comment: You haven't made any effort to define exactly which numbers you want to wrap and which you don't  want to wrap so as I said, it is up to you to identify your exact requirements. Whether it is then possible to translate them into regular expressions we'll see, but if you can't describe more precisely which numbers at at which positions in the text you need to wrap and which ones not then there is no way to come up with a precise regular expression.

Comment: @Martin Honnen - Yes! you are correct and i'm still working on it and will let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<xsl:template match="//text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(, )([0-9][^a-z]+$)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="regex-group(2)" regex="(, |–)">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <locator><xsl:value-of select="."/></locator>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEcZxA

Comment: Thank you Rupesh i have added new cases in last, and update the comment which have problem please see transformation on the following link https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbpGG/1

Comment: @Umaima see updated transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbpGG/2

Comment: Thank you Rupesh all the cases are fine but only one case is pending see last entry i added on followoing link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxN9PRN/2

Comment: @Umaima updated. see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxN9PRN/3

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything going well we have only the issue if we adding 'bold' element in that case skip only i.e. <h1><bold>Budapest Treaty,</bold> 17.14</h1>, If we removed 'bold' from 'h1' it will work please see  examples added in the last: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9NXUQ/2

Comment: @Umaima, that is a totally different scenario in respect with other, so it need different approach, or you just need to clean input by move "," outside the bold element, this will not impact your output

Comment: Can you please share your email id.

Comment: @Umaima,rupesh4only@gmail.com

Comment: We have shared one test case please help me.

Comment: At your gmail id.